# Finding average of multiple delta times

Tags: postgresql, select, aggregate, window-functions

I'm looking to find the average interval between successive rows across the whole query - `delta-previous` in below example:

```
SELECT *,
  "RecognitionTimestamp" - lag("RecognitionTimestamp") OVER(ORDER BY "RecognitionTimestamp") AS delta_previous,
FROM "Detection" 
WHERE
  "RecognitionTimestamp" >= '2018-10-03 09:01:00' AND 
  "RecognitionTimestamp" <= '2018-10-04 09:00:00'
```

How can I do this?
I've tried `avg("delta_previous")`, `avg(delta_previous)`,`avg("RecognitionTimestamp" - lag("RecognitionTimestamp"))`

Comment: It helps to disclose your Postgres version and table definition (`CREATE TABLE` script). So we see data types and constraints. And the version is often relevant for the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to run aggregate function over an expression involving a window function in the same query level, because aggregate functions are evaluated *before* window functions. You'd need a subquery like:

```
SELECT avg(delta_previous) AS avg_delta_previous
FROM (
   SELECT "RecognitionTimestamp"
        - lag("RecognitionTimestamp") OVER(ORDER BY "RecognitionTimestamp") AS delta_previous,
   FROM   "Detection" 
   WHERE  "RecognitionTimestamp" >= '2018-10-03 09:01:00'
   AND    "RecognitionTimestamp" <  '2018-10-04 09:00:00'  -- typically, you'd want "<" here, not "<="!
   ) sub;
```

Consider the sequence of events in a `SELECT` query:

- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied/8242764#8242764)

But this simpler query should give you the same result, only **much cheaper**:

```
SELECT (max("RecognitionTimestamp")
      - min("RecognitionTimestamp")) / (count(*) - 1) AS avg_delta_previous
FROM   "Detection" 
WHERE  "RecognitionTimestamp" >= '2018-10-03 09:01:00'
AND    "RecognitionTimestamp" <  '2018-10-04 09:00:00';
```

Subtract the *minimum* from the *maximum* timestamp to get the total interval and divide it by *the number or rows - 1*. Voilá.